# remove hyperlink keep content within

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove the outer `a`? and use text() to alter the content within?

```
<a><span>content</span></a>
```

this will not work because it will remove the entire tag.

```
$("span").text('Altered content').closest('a').remove();
```

My desire outcome would be this `<span>Altered Content</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)** along with `.text()` to set the text value:

> Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

```
$('a span').unwrap().text('altered content');
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, as others have said, you need the `unwrap()` function. But instead of using the span tag, I would recommend using an `id` or `class` as the selector. The way unwrap works, is it removes the parent and leaves only the selector itself.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3amdu54/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $("span").unwrap();
    $("span").text('replaced text');
});
```